# Community flags question that's migrated without comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, closed-questions, migration, community-user

If I migrate a question without comments, community flags it the same as if it is closed without a comment. Under normal circumstances, it's helpful to let a user know why the question was closed, but a migration seems like it's pretty clear to my why it's closed. Do we really need this to be flagged?